# Motivation for the Weil function for a Cartier divisor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, diophantine-approximation

I'm not sure if this is the right place for a question like this.

In Diophantine approximation, on a complex variety $X$ there is a notion of a *Weil function* for a Cartier divisor $D$ on $X$ which is defined as follows:

> A *local Weil function* for $D$ is a function $\lambda_D: (X \setminus \mathrm{Supp}\, D) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x \in X$ there is an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ in $X$, a function $f \in \Gamma(U,\mathcal{O})$ with $D|_U = (f)$, and a continuous function $\alpha: U \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $$\lambda_D(x) = -\log |f(x)| + \alpha(x)$$ for all $x \in (X \setminus\mathrm{Supp}\, D)$.

What is the motivation behind such a definition? By the property of a Cartier divisor, I can understand how the condition $f \in \Gamma(U ,\mathcal{O})$ with $D|_U = (f)$ can be satisfied, but I don't quite understand the rest of the definition.

1. Why do we consider points away from the support of $D$?
2. How do we think about the continuous function $\alpha$? Or rather, what is its purpose?

As an example, the Weil function for the hyperplane $H = \{a_0x_0+...+a_nx_n = 0\}$ on $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{C})$ is given by $$\lambda_H(x) = \log \frac{\max_{0 \leq i \leq n} |x_i| \max_{0 \leq i \leq n}|a_i|}{|a_0x_0+...+a_nx_n|},$$
where $x = [x_0:...:x_n]$. In this case, we consider points away from the support of $H$ so that $\lambda_H$ can be defined. But I'm not sure if this is always the case. Also, the continuous function $\alpha$ here seems to be zero.